# Will this raspberry pi circuit work?

Tags: dc-motor, raspberry-pi

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTwZ1E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will this circuit work with the raspberry pi and will the rpi be safe? I want the motor to turn on when GPIO_2 is set high. It is a DC motor and the transistor is a BC635 (I couldn't change the parameters on the diagram).

Comment: What current does the motor need to take in your application?

Answer (score 3):

Your motor needs to be current limited to 1A or you are likely to damage the BC635. I also think there may be a chance that your GPIO current may not be sufficient to drive the transistor to get ~1A into the motor: -

[image]

What this part of the data sheet tells you is the to get 500 mA into the motor requires a base current that is only 25 times smaller at 20 mA - you need to verify that your GPIO can supply this current without risk to the RaPi.

Note also that if you need to activate your motor to close to 9V under mechanical heavy (ish) loads you might even have to push 50 mA into the base of the transistor.

And of course, you always need a base resistor because the GPIO pin may be able to supply more than 50 mA i.e. the base resistor is there to protect the transistor and the GPIO pin.

---

RaPi current appears to be about 16mA maximum according to [this](http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Raspberry/Understanding_Outputs.html) document below: -

[image]

See also [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9298/what-is-the-maximum-current-the-gpio-pins-can-output) on SE.RaPi

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit will work, although you must add a resistor to limit the base current of the transistor.

Comment: @MattYoung - I replaced 'should' with 'must', perhaps it would be more clear that way ;)